# Create bucket of 2 documents - Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a set of documents having timestamps. I want to sort them in ascending order of timestamp and then bucket them into documents of two.

Suppose documents have timestamps `1,2,3,4`

I want to bucket them into sets of two i.e `1,2 in one bucket, 2 and 4 in the next bucket.` How do I do this in elasticsearch?

Comment: Do you want to compute any aggregation from the document pairs? Could you just search for the documents normally in the timestamp order and then process them programatically in pairs?

Comment: Yes, I want to compute sum aggregation from the document pairs. Instead of programmatically processing them in pairs, if we can natively do it using aggregations with elasticsearch, won't it be faster?

Answer (score 0):

There is no good way to scale the bucket sizes dynamically based on the content (the main reason is, that you would need to change your bucket strategy on every document, if they are not sorted by the criteria you query for). Imagine that 1,2,3,4 are timestamps, but the timestamps in your data are not sorted...

I think it would be much easier to solve this on index time and join those documents there (and also do the sum work on index time), but maybe I just dont know enough about that use-case...